# Can someone show me an easy way to test a Phonegap app on a Playbook?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-playbook

I am currently developing an app in Phonegap, and need to test it on a playbook. But all the tutorials I've been able to find (not many) haven't been able to explain how to do this on a mac. Can someone help me with this? We've been able to launch it on a blackberry, just not the playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this link (just posted about a week ago) will help:
[Getting Started with PhoneGap on Playbook by Joe Lambert](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2012/02/07/getting-started-with-phonegap-on-blackberry-playbook/)

He has screen shots and pretty thorough descriptions of running the HelloWorld sample app on the Playbook simulator and actual device. Playbook support from Phonegap has been added so recently (less than a month) that online documentation about it is sparse at best. Good luck!